# Newbie in CSS: how to set the element position in my case?

Tags: css

I have

```
<input type='text', id='name'></input>
```

and I have

```
<p>my name is xyz</p>
```

I would  like the `<p>` element to be located **20px** the **right** side of `<input>`, how to use **CSS** to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is a little bit more work than simply adding a CSS style declaration, but could I suggest that you use slightly-more semantic mark-up to style your forms? Something along the lines of:

```
<form action="path/to/script.php" method="post">
    <fieldset> <!-- to associate related inputs -->
        <legend>Name</legend> <!-- a broad description of this group of inputs -->
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" /> <!-- input elements are usually self-closing -->
        <label for="name">My name is</label> <!-- the for attribute takes the id of the associated input, and allows a click on the label to focus the input -->
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Then, in the CSS, if you want the `label` to be 20px to the right of the `input`, all you need to do is:

```
input {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

/* or */

label {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo of `margin-right`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GNJY7/1/).
[JS Fiddle demo of `margin-left`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GNJY7/).

Recommended reading:

- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms
- http://www.themaninblue.com/writing/perspective/2004/03/24/

Answer (score 0):

```
<label><input type='text', id='name'><span style="padding-left:20px;">my name is xyz</span></label>
```

Comment: For some reason, I would like to use external css file to approach the result, because the elements are dynamically created, not inline style. But thank you!

Comment: @Mellon: just a tip, never use inline styles

Comment: inline styles are for example only.

Answer (score 0):

You can float the elements to achieve this:

```
input { float: left; }
p {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```